# Deleting rows in SQL by query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have about a million rows of data in a table. I want to delete of every 5 rows of the last 3 rows.

Example:

```
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
Row5
Row6
Row7
Row8
Row9
Row10
```

After I delete them it should look like this :

```
Row1
Row2
Row6
Row7
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but you need to specify some column in `order by`.
And there should be some other rule to delete those records.

```
DROP TABLE _test
GO
create table _test
(id int identity(1,1)
 ,x int 
)
GO
insert into _test(x)
select 1
go 50


;with cte as (
    select [rwn] = row_number() over(partition by 1 order by id)
    from _test
)
delete from cte 
where 1=1
    and rwn%5 not in (1,2)

select * from _test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement. it is works

```
delete from temp12  where Reg_No in (select Reg_No from  
(select Reg_No,Name, Row_number() over (order by reg_no) abc from temp12 )
 where  abc  like '%3' or abc like '%4' or abc like '%5' or abc like '%8' or abc like '%9'  or abc like '%0')
```